# How do you call types that tend to spread over the whole codebase like a string type?

Tags: c++, types

When watching C++ videos on YouTube, I heard people use a special word for types that tend to spread over the whole codebase, because they are very commonly used and often used to make interfaces more expressive, like `std::string`, `QString`, `QPoint`, `std::path` etc.

I think they used the name *lexical type* but I am having a hard time to confirm that via Google and I am not sure if that was the word.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable name for them.  I'm not sure what else you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the term is *vocabulary type*. At least, that is the term used during discussions at Committee meetings.

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for. Thank you. Here is one reference that uses this name: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joaquintides/usingstdcpp2017/master/C%2B%2B17%20vocabulary%20types/C%2B%2B17%20vocabulary%20types.pdf